# Why does TypeScript require the deriving class to call super(), even though the parent class has no constructor?

Tags: typescript, constructor, super

I'm new-ish to class-based programming, I'm working on an API made in TypeScript.

Let's say I've got this code:

```js
import { Router } from "express";

export default class BaseController {
  public router = Router();
}
```

and I extend another class from that:

```js
import BaseController from "./BaseController";

export default FooController extends BaseController {
  constuctor() {
    // I will elaborate on this super later in the question
    super();
    this.router.get("/", this.faz);
  }

  private faz(req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.status(200).send("boo!");
  }
}
```

When I remove `super();` my code will not compile because of the following error message: `Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.`

I know that `super` is used to call the constructor for the parent class, but my parent class does not need nor does not have a constructor. This basically means that i'm calling an empty function.

**Question: Why do I need to call `super();` on a derived class, when the parent class has no constructor? *(So you basically don't call anything if I'm correct)***

Comment: Parent does have a constructor. It's just not explicit.

Comment: @ritaj Oh, ok. So there's no way to avoid this..?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: You cannot access `this` until `super` has been called which comes from ES6 IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check how it will be transpiled to javascript in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

from your example property initializer will be moved into constructor therefore call to super is demanded

```
export default class BaseController {
    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does not strictly check whether super() is actually callable. So you can omit super() call if you really want it by doing

```
export default FooController extends BaseController {
    constructor() {
        if (false) super()
    }
}
```

but this is not recommended at all, especially in your case as your super() call is mandatory because you have a pre-initialized property `public router`, which implicitly initializes in the constructor (which can be seen in JavaScript code).